# Azure certificate in Key Vault not valid for app service

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

The script below will generate a self-signed certificate, create a password secured pfx and add the certificate to the key vault.
When I run the ARM template after the script, it fails with the error below.
However, when I manually upload the pfx in the UI (Azure portal) and enter the correct password, the ARM template will get successfully deployed.
Any ideas how to get this working?

PowerShell code (when uploading the generated pfx in the portal, no error is thrown):

```
# Generate the certificate in the local store
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject "CN=$certificateName" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable

# Get the raw value of the certificate
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -Password $certPasswordSecure -FilePath "d:/temp/SelfSigned.pfx"

$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $keyValue -AsPlainText –Force 
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12' 

Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $keyVaultSecretNameCertificate -SecretValue $keyValue -ContentType $secretContentType
```

The error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 21:22:36 - Resource Microsoft.Web/certificates 'testCertificate' failed with message '{
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value.",
        "ExtendedCode": "51008",
        "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
        "Parameters": [
          "KeyVault Certificate"
        ],
        "InnerErrors": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}'
At line:3 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name TestKeyVaultDeploy -Resource ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 21:23:11 - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations 
for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At line:3 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name TestKeyVaultDeploy -Resource ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 21:23:11 - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations 
for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At line:3 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name TestKeyVaultDeploy -Resource ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

ARM Certificate Resource:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
            "name": "testCertificate",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "keyVaultId": "[parameters('masterKeyVaultId')]",
                "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('servicePrincipalCertSecretName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing the certificate policy on upload?
But really if you're generating new certs then why bother generating certificate locally, just generate it in the key vault itself.

```
$credential = Get-Credential

login-azurermaccount -Credential $credential
$vaultName = 'my-vault-full-of-keys'
$certificateName = 'my-new-cert'
$policy = New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SubjectName "CN=mememe.me" -IssuerName Self -ValidityInMonths 120
Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName -CertificatePolicy $policy
```